# Freeze when using tkinter + pyhook. Two event loops and multithreading

Tags: multithreading, tkinter, event-loop, pyhook

I am writing a tool in python 2.7 registering the amount of times the user pressed a keyboard or mouse button. The amount of clicks will be displayed in a small black box in the top left of the screen. The program registers clicks even when another application is the active one.

It works fine except when I move the mouse over the box. The mouse then freezes for a few seconds after which the program works again. If I then move the mouse over the box a second time, the mouse freezes again, but this time the program crashes.

I have tried commenting out pumpMessages() and then the program works. The problem looks a lot like this question [pyhook+tkinter=crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765362/pyhook-tkinter-crash), but no solution was given there.

Other answers has shown that there is a bug with the dll files when using wx and pyhook together in python 2.6. I don't know if that is relevant here.

My own thoughts is that it might have something to do with the two event loops running parallel. I have read that tkinter isn't thread safe, but I can't see how I can make this program run in a single thread since I need to have both pumpmessages() and mainlooop() running.

To sum it up: Why does my program freeze on mouse over?

```
import pythoncom, pyHook, time, ctypes, sys
from Tkinter import *
from threading import Thread

print 'Welcome to APMtool. To exit the program press delete'

## Creating input hooks

#the function called when a MouseAllButtonsUp event is called
def OnMouseUpEvent(event): 
    global clicks
    clicks+=1
    updateCounter()
    return True

#the function called when a KeyUp event is called
def OnKeyUpEvent(event): 
    global clicks
    clicks+=1
    updateCounter()
    if (event.KeyID == 46):
        killProgram()
    return True


hm = pyHook.HookManager()# create a hook manager

# watch for mouseUp and keyUp events
hm.SubscribeMouseAllButtonsUp(OnMouseUpEvent)
hm.SubscribeKeyUp(OnKeyUpEvent)

clicks = 0

hm.HookMouse()# set the hook
hm.HookKeyboard()

## Creating the window
root = Tk()
label = Label(root,text='something',background='black',foreground='grey')
label.pack(pady=0) #no space around the label
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1) #alway the top window
root.overrideredirect(1) #removes the 'Windows 7' box around the label

## starting a new thread to run pumMessages() and mainloop() simultaniusly
def startRootThread():
    root.mainloop()

def updateCounter():
    label.configure(text=clicks)

def killProgram():
    ctypes.windll.user32.PostQuitMessage(0) # stops pumpMessages
    root.destroy() #stops the root widget
    rootThread.join()
    print 'rootThread stopped'



rootThread = Thread(target=startRootThread)
rootThread.start()

pythoncom.PumpMessages() #pump messages is a infinite loop waiting for events

print 'PumpMessages stopped'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the information that Tkinter needs to run in the main thread and not be called outside this thred, I found a solution:

My problem was that both `PumpMessages` and `mainLoop` needed to run in the main thread. In order to both receive inputs and show a Tkinter label with the amount of clicks I need to switch between running `pumpMessages` and briefly running `mainLoop` to update the display.

To make `mainLoop()` quit itself I used:

```
after(100,root.quit()) #root is the name of the Tk()
mainLoop()
```

so after 100 milliseconds `root` calls it's `quit` method and breaks out of its own main loop

To break out of pumpMessages I first found the pointer to the main thread:

```
mainThreadId = win32api.GetCurrentThreadId()
```

I then used a new thread that sends the `WM_QUIT` to the main thread (note `PostQuitMessage(0)` only works if it is called in the main thread):

```
win32api.PostThreadMessage(mainThreadId, win32con.WM_QUIT, 0, 0)
```

It was then possible to create a while loop which changed between `pumpMessages` and `mainLoop`, updating the labeltext in between. After the two event loops aren't running simultaneously anymore, I have had no problems:

```
def startTimerThread():
    while True:
        win32api.PostThreadMessage(mainThreadId, win32con.WM_QUIT, 0, 0)
        time.sleep(1)

mainThreadId = win32api.GetCurrentThreadId()
timerThread = Thread(target=startTimerThread)
timerThread.start()

while programRunning:
    label.configure(text=clicks)
    root.after(100,root.quit)
    root.mainloop()
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Thank you to Bryan Oakley for information about Tkinter and Boaz Yaniv for providing the information needed to [stop pumpMessages() from a subthread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023172/ending-a-program-mid-run/6023566#6023566)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem with multiprocessing:

1. the main process handles the GUI (MainThread) and a thread that consumes messages from the second process
2. a child process hooks all mouse/keyboard events and pushes them to the main process (via a Queue object)

Comment: How did you check the Queue in the main thread? Didn't it block the qui?

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter isn't designed to be run from any thread other than the main one. It might help to put the GUI in the main thread and put the call to `PumpMessages` in a separate thread. Though you have to be careful and not call any Tkinter functions from the other thread (except perhaps `event_generate`).

Comment: Ok, that could be it. I already tried to put pumpmessages() in another thread, but it didn't work. I found somewhere that pumpmessages() is also only designed to run in the main thread. Any suggestions for an alternative gui then? Or another workaround?